# UIWebView inside StoryBoard segue controller not taking fullscreen in Landscape mode in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I am experiencing an issue with the storyboard and UIWebView.

I have a UIWebView inside a Navigation Controller in my history board, and when I am presenting it in landscape it is not taking the full screen of the device. Is there a way to do this? I already checked in the storyboard and the presentation type is set as "Full Screen".

Is there a way to force this?

Attached is a screen of what I see. What I pretend is to not have any dark area and to have all the webview covering the screen except for the status bar.

[image]